# Expand items of DropDownList dynamically in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdown

I am uisng asp.net c#. Here I want to Expand the items of a `DropDownList` dynamically means in Code Behind.

In my research I found that it would be possible using `JQuery` like

```
$('#countries').attr('size',6);
```

Which is actually making the `DropDownList` to `ListBox`, any way it was expanding.

But I want this to happen in `c#`, may be inside button click event or any event.

Thank you your valuable suggestion will be highly appreciate.

Comment: `size` attribute doesn't expands the dropdown items dynamically it just sets _the number of visible options in a drop-down list_. What you are trying to do?

Comment: ok I got it, but i want to display all the items

Comment: You still didn't answered my question. What you are trying to do exactly? You want to add new items to your dropdown? If yes then when you want to do this?

Comment: If you want to add new items, do it. If you instead want to change layout apply the appropriate CSS(`via CssClass` or `Style`-attributes) or use the `Width`/`Height` properties.

Comment: I want that all items of a dropdownlist should be visible when i click on a button instead of clicking on the dropdownlist. @Rahul Singh

Comment: What you're trying to do is not possible. You'll have to use a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this dynamically by adding to the `Attributes` collection:

```
DropDownList1.Attributes.Add("size", "10");
```

Comment: it is making the dropdownlist to a listbox, i dont want to change it to listbox

Comment: i want only that popup the items like when i click on the dropdown itself

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to mimic browser behaviour by having the dropdown list expanded on the initial load of the page.

If that sounds right then try the [JQuery simulate plugin](https://github.com/eduardolundgren/jquery-simulate/blob/master/jquery.simulate.js)

And then try something like:

```
$("#countries").simulate('mousedown');
```